# HTTP EventSource with POST

Tags: javascript, http, streaming, eventsource

I've implemented event source streaming (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) at the server side via a POST request with some parameters. I mean, when I send a POST request to the server with some parameters, it returns the result based on the parameters. I've tested it with the Insomnia App of Google Chrome and it works but I'm afraid the EventSource API in javascript does not let me to send a POST request to the server.

Am I missing something? Is sending a POST request to an URI that serves an event stream not a standard?

Comment: What is purpose of using `POST`?

Comment: @guest271314 the idea is to send parameters with the request and I don't want parameters in the url

Comment: You could `POST` request to another `php` page using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`